# Disabling and Enabling a a radiobutton based on option selected in dropdownlist in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have a radio button option i want to disable and enable based on an option selected from a drop down list. I have the radio button option originally disabled but when I attempt to enable it based on the option selected in the drop down list nothing happens. could i get some help with this: 
HTML:

```
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1">
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="0" />
                  <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
                  <asp:ListItem Text="2/Staff" Value="2" />
                  <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />                      
                  <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
                  <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />                     
            </asp:DropDownList> 
          <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbPType" ClientIDMode="Static">
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="T0"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

JS:

```
$('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", true);
$('#ddl1').change(function () {

    if ($(this).children('option:selected').text() == "2")
    {
        $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", true);
    }

});
```

PS: My orignal intention was to hide and show this based on the option and got stomped. So if there is a way to hide and show rather than enable and disable I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: will asp solution do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the dropdownlist's selected value by using `.val()`

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2/Staff" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbPType" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="T0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<script>
    $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#ddl1').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == '2') {
            $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", true);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I didnt want to disable the whole list. I just wanted to disable value 1. I just grabbed the rbPType_1 from source code and it seemed to work in that one instance

Comment: I had that at one point and it still doesnt enable it on when i selection option 2

Comment: `$(this).children('option:selected').text() == "2/Staff"` should work instead of `... == "2"`.

Comment: I tried that at one point too and it just doesnt budge. By chance would you have a hide/show solution to this?

Comment: I tried `if ($(this).val() == '2') {` and `if ($(this).children('option:selected').text() == "2/Staff") {`. They both work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26890/discussion-between-robertpurpose-and-win)

Comment: this is what I have: $('#ddlAffiliation').change(function () {

        if ($(this).children('option:selected').text() == "2/Staff") {
            $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('#rbPType_1').attr("disabled", true);
        }
       
    });

Comment: ddl1 instead of ddlAffliation

Comment: Above code works for me. I'm using `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: sad part is im using 1.9.1 and I am pretty sure it should still be working. So definately must be doing something wrong

Comment: I test with 1.9.1 and still work. Please note that if you have a javascript error in other code, all scripts might stop working.

Comment: Well the other events i have set up are still working so I am pretty sure it is just that one event

Answer (score 0):

Try this as JS:

```
$('#rbPType_1').hide();
$('#ddl1').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == ("2"||"2/Staff")) {
        $('#rbPType_1').show();
    } else {
        $('#rbPType_1').hide();
    }
});
```

It *should* work

Comment: This one still had it disabled Im not sure why

Comment: Oh Im sorry I replied to the wrong person. When it is hidden and shown it doesnt take the label with it. Thats why I was looking around for a way to take that row with it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rbPType_1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#ddl1').on('change',function () {
    if($(this).val()=='2'){
        $('#rbPType_1').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
        $('#rbPType_1').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
})
```

Comment: This one still had it disabled Im not sure why

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        Height="28px" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        Width="100px">
        <asp:ListItem>Value one</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Value Two</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and set the Event

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        RadioButton1.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        RadioButton1.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

try this and implement it as you need .

Comment: I tried something similar to this and it still doesnt become enabled on the else. Even in the JS its being stubborn